# Why is git not allowing me to update?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'm writing an operating system in C with VScode. I have a github repo that suddenly stopped working.

Under "SOURCE CONTROL" in VScode, there are 0 changes, and when I attempt to commit, it says "There are no changes to commit".

When I try the terminal:

```
 git add --all
 git commit -m "x"
```

I get this message:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Not sure what's going on here. How can I fix/ reset git without losing my changes?

Comment: Have you done an initial add? The `git add --all` only adds files that are already in the repository.

Comment: this message usually appears when the latest changes are already updated in git, try editing some lines of code and push to git.

Comment: Also do `git status` to see the current status of modified files (if any).

Answer (score 0):

Considering there are 0 pending changes to be added (and committed), check the history:

```
git log
git show
```

The [`git show`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show) command will show you the content of the most recent commit of your current HEAD. You might recognize the changes you wanted to add/commit, confirming those are already tracked.